# FutureWarning on using np.full to create array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, warnings

I used the following to create a contact array in python using numpy.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.full((2,2), 7) 
print(a)
```

It did print the expected array.

```
[[ 7.  7.]
 [ 7.  7.]]
```

I got the following warning also after the value was printed :

> FutureWarning: in the future, `full((2, 2), 7)` will return an array of `dtype('int64')`.

Can someone please explain what this means? Also is this something important or can be ignored (which we generally do with warnings :P).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's wise to ignore this `FutureWarning` because what until now created a `float` array will change to an `int` array in the future. Note that you specified an integer 7 as fill-value but the result was a float-array. I assume the numpy-developers considered that this behaviour is inconsistent and want to change the behaviour in the future.

If you want an `int` array you should explicitly specify the `dtype=int`:

```
>>> np.full((2, 2), 7, dtype=int)
array([[7, 7],
       [7, 7]])
```

If you want a `float` array, just change `7` to a `float`: `7.`:

```
>>> np.full((2, 2), 7.)
array([[ 7.,  7.],
       [ 7.,  7.]])
```

It's also possible to specify the dtype explicitly `dtype=float`:

```
>>> np.full((2,2), 7, dtype=float)
array([[ 7.,  7.],
       [ 7.,  7.]])
```

In all three cases the `FutureWarning` goes away without the need to explicitly ignore the `FutureWarning`.

I wouldn't recommend it but if you don't care if it's an integer or float array and don't like that Warning you can explicitly suppress it:

```
import warnings
import numpy as np

with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter('ignore', FutureWarning)
    arr = np.full((2,2), 7)
```